# Max number of particular sequence of elements in 3D array

Tags: arrays, math, multidimensional-array, mathematical-optimization, discrete-mathematics

So for a data structures assignment, I had to initialize each element in a statically allocated 3D array with one of five colors chosen at random. The array was of type ColorEnum, which was declared like this:

---

enum ColorEnum { RED, ORANGE, YELLOW, GREEN, BLUE };

---

My task was to find the indices of the elements that make up a particular sequence of elements (meaning each element in the sequence is logically touching the next element in the sequence either by side to side, top to bottom, or front to back). A complete sequence would be one in which a RED element is touching an ORANGE element which is touching a YELLOW element which is touching a GREEN element which is touching a BLUE element. To be touching, an entire side of both elements have to be adjacent, not just an edge or corner. So each element could be touching at maximum 6 other elements. An individual element can be used in more than one sequence. In order to store the indices of the elements in a sequence, I used a statically allocated 1D array of structs which would hold the row, column, and depth indices of the element. In order to store each sequence, I used another statically allocated 1D array of the arrays which hold the indices of the elements in a sequence. Getting to my question, in order to use as little memory as possible, I need to know what size to allocate to the array of arrays. I would like this size to be equal to the maximum number of these RED, ORANGE, YELLOW, GREEN, BLUE sequences but I don't know how to determine this number. Any math geniuses out there care to give me a hand? My assignment is long been finished. I got a 94/100, but this question is bugging me. I appreciate the help.

Comment: So you have a collection of objects, but you don't know ahead of time how many you'll have. Sounds like a textbook use case for [vectors](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)!

Comment: Exactly, I'm just interested in how a mathematician would determine the maximum number of these "objects".

Answer (score 0):

The maximum amount of possible sequences will depend on the dimensions of your 3D array and (of course) the filling of the grid. Looking at it from a combinatorial angle, I would try and find the most efficient filling of such a 3D grid. However, allocating the maximum is assuming the worst case and you would be better of with vectors as @Kevin commented.

One filling of the grid that seems efficient to me is to fill the 6 adjacent positions of 1 block with 3 of its previous colors and 3 of its next colors (so a yellow block would have 3 orange and 3 green blocks as neighbors). If you fill the (back, right, up) neighbors with the next color and the (front, left, down) neighbors with the previous color, then the emerging structure allows 1 block to be used in a lot of sequences. If a color doesn't have a next/previous color, just the previous/next color.

In 2D you would have something like this (abbreviated colornames)

```
BGYOROYGBGYOROYGB
GBGYOROYGBGYOROYG
YGBGYOROYGBGYOROY
OYGBGYOROYGBGYORO
ROYGBGYOROYGBGYOR
```

The number of sequences using the bottom-left R is 2^4, the amount of sequences using one of the middle R's (in an infinite field) is 2^5. The exact total nr of sequences in a 3D field can then be calculated for this pattern, taking into account the boundaries (and probably a different scheme at the edges as there will be some loss)

My filling method is just one way of filling the grid, other possibilities exist and might even be better.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the time you took to write this answer.  I forgot to mention in my question that the 3D array's dimensions are 5x5x5.  That would eliminate one variable.  However, like you said, there may be another method of filling the array which would be better.  I posted this question out of mere curiosity of a mathematical formula that could be used to solve the problem I stated.